Multiple dichotomous variable, data representation for analysis and plotting
I am trying to analyse a dataset which has several dichotomous columns describing infections and pathogens. Neither types of infections nor pathogens are mutually exclusive.
I'm struggling to find a good way of representing my dataset for descriptive analysis and plotting.
Here an example of the data structure:
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)

d <- tidyr::tibble(
  id = c(1:20),
  et_yn = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 20, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")), label = "ET")
) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    inf_1 = factor(ifelse(et_yn == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
    inf_2 = factor(ifelse(et_yn == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
    et_typ_1 = factor(ifelse(et_yn == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
    et_typ_2 = factor(ifelse(et_yn == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(0:1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
    inf_2_typ = factor(ifelse(inf_2 == "Yes", sample(seq(1,3), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(1:3), labels = c("sup", "deep", "organ")),
    et_entero = factor(ifelse(et_typ_1 == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA),
                       levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")),
    et_gp_1 = factor(ifelse(et_typ_2 == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
    et_gp_2 = factor(ifelse(et_typ_2 == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
    et_gp_3 = factor(ifelse(et_typ_2 == "Yes", sample(seq(0,1), size = 1, replace = T), NA), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  ) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(
    inf_1 = structure(inf_1, label = "BSI"),
    inf_2 = structure(inf_2, label = "SSI"),
    inf_2_typ = structure(inf_2_typ, label = "SSI Type"),
    et_typ_1 = structure(et_typ_1, label = "ET gn"),
    et_typ_2 = structure(et_typ_2, label = "ET gp"),
    et_entero = structure(et_entero, label = "GN Entero"),
    et_gp_1 = structure(et_gp_1, label = "St.a"),
    et_gp_2 = structure(et_gp_2, label = "St.b"),
    et_gp_3 = structure(et_gp_3, label = "St.c"),
  )

Created on 2024-12-30 with reprex v2.1.1
The objective is to explore the relationship between inf_X and various et_typ_X/et_gp_X and to describe incidence of various inf_X and various et_gp_X.
Below an example table:



Infection
N of events




Type of infection



  SSI
X (xx%)


    superficial
X (xx%)


    deep
X (xx%)


    organ
X (xx%)


  BSI
X (xx%)


and so on ...




And something similar for the pathogens:



Characteristic
N
n (%)




ET
20
7 (35%)


ET gn
7
3 (43%)


ET gp
7
2 (29%)


GN Entero
3



 Unchecked

2 (67%)


 Checked

1 (33%)


GP
2



 St.a

0 (0%)


 St.b

1 (50%)


 St.c

1 (50%)



For graphs maybe a treemap or a nested pie chart graph could work for this purpose, but I'm struggling to find a way to create these representations with this data.
Is there a recommended way to structure the data for this purpose?
Thank you.
